# Print tracking number on prestashop invoice

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, invoice

how can I add/print tracking number on invoice?..

I used the code below

```
{l s='Tracking Number:' pdf='true'}
{$order->shipping_number}
```

returns blank, but on view order it has a tracking number. (image below)

orders->shipping_number field is blank.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: $shipping_number is deprecatred since 1.5.0.4. but sometimes it still gets the data. but try using {$order->getWsShippingNumber()}

Comment: thanks. already solved the issue by using
`{$line.tracking_number}`

Answer (score 0):

adding on invoice.tpl

```
{foreach from=$order->getShipping() item=line}
    {if $line.url != '' || $line.tracking_number != ''}
        {'Tracking Number : '}
        {$line.tracking_number}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

solves the issue.